# Drupal: access to email address field of referenced User in an entity

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-rules

I have two content types:

- business partner (B)
- service (S)

The relationship is as follows: S --> B

It means in service content type, I have a field named business_partner_ref with Entity Reference type. In business partner content type, I have a field named account_manager-ref with Entity Reference type which refers to drupal User
entity.

I want an email has been sent to account manager of a business partner when a change occurs in workflow state of service content type. So in action part of rules module I add a send mail action and in from part of it, I use the token [node:business_partner_ref:account_manager-ref:mail]. But it leave empty string in TO field of email action. When I user [node:business_partner_ref:account_manager-ref] it prints the username of account manager!

Is it a bug or my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it has something to do with the double reference (ref node, ref user). I use a similar Rule, but I'm targeting the author of the referenced node and it works fine. I would expect your method to work. If it's not a limitation of daisy-chaining references, could be a bug.